# Find the Laurent series of $\frac{1}{z^2(1-z)}$ when $0< |z-1| < 1$.

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Find the Laurent series of $\frac{1}{z^2(1-z)}$ when $0< |z-1| < 1$.

I don't quite know how to deal with this particular sum. Usually, I would set $w = z-1$, and that would give me

$$-\frac{1}{w(w-1)^2}$$

and I would need to find the expansion of this in the region $0 < |w| < 1$. But I can't figure out how to handle this series! Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you want the Laurent series centered at $z=1$. I'll perform the same variable change as you, $w=z-1$. Let's warm up with the following series:
$$
\frac{1}{(w+1)^2}=\left(\sum_{n\geq 0}(-w)^n\right)^2=\sum_{n\geq 0}(n+1)(-w)^n,\quad |w|<1.
$$
Replacing $w=z-1$ yields
$$
\frac{1}{z^2}=\sum_{n\geq 0}(n+1)(1-z)^n.
$$
Therefore the Laurent series is given by
$$
\frac{1}{z^2(1-z)}=\sum_{n\geq 0}(n+1)(1-z)^{n-1}.
$$
Note that this includes a negative power of $(1-z)$.